# apt-get - How to complain on failed upgrade?

Tags: scripting, apt

I'm trying to write a script to upgrade a bunch of remote machines and would like to verify that one package in particular is upgraded.

With `yum`, I could say `yum upgrade specific-package`, and it would complain if it fails to upgrade the package.  With `apt`, as far as I know, I can only say `apt-get upgrade`, and if `apt` fails to find the new version or fails to resolve the dependencies for the new version, it will silently decide not to install it.

Is there any way to get `apt-get` to complain if it decides to not upgrade a package (short of scripting a call to `dpkg --compare-versions`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use *apt-get install* to do what you want. The apt-get manpage says the following:

> This is also the target to use if you want to upgrade one or more
>              already-installed packages without upgrading every package you have
>              on your system. Unlike the "upgrade" target, which installs the
>              newest version of all currently installed packages, "install" will
>              install the newest version of only the package(s) specified. Simply
>              provide the name of the package(s) you wish to upgrade, and if a
>              newer version is available, it (and its dependencies, as described
>              above) will be downloaded and installed.

If you are wanting to install a known version of a package you can specify that on the commandline too.

```
apt-get install apache2=2.2.14-5ubuntu8.3
```